# Is there an opposite of np.take for multi-dimensional case in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I have `N`-D array `a` and 1-D array `indexes` and `axis`, what is the shortest/easiest way to assign values to sub-array of `a` indexed with these indexes along given axis?

If `N` and `axis` are known/fixed at code writing time then I can easily do

```
a[:,   :,   :,   indexes,   :,   :] = b
               ^^axis pos^^
```

but what if `N` and `axis` are known only at runtime, e.g. after user inputing some data.

The easiest form that I have figured out is this:

```
a[(slice(None),) * (axis % a.ndim) + (indexes,)] = b
```

But maybe there's some built-in function?

There's [np.put](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) but it seems to work only on flattened array, doesn't support multi-dimensionality.

There's also [np.take](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html), which works for multi-dimensional case, but is the opposite of what I need, it reads data instead of writing, although has exact syntax that I'm looking for in writing. You can do like this:

```
b = np.take(a, indexes, axis)
```

So is there an opposite of `np.take`? Like `np.nd_put`, that can do:

```
np.nd_put(a, indexes, axis, b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to permute axes to bring that `axis` to the front and simply index -

```
np.moveaxis(a,axis,0)[indexes] = np.moveaxis(b,axis,0)
```

Another with `np.put_along_axis` if you are looking for something built around a bultin -

```
i = [None]*b.ndim
i[axis] = Ellipsis
np.put_along_axis(a, indexes[tuple(i)], b, axis=axis)
```

For completeness, here's the slice version -

```
i = [slice(None)]*b.ndim
i[axis] = indexes
a[tuple(i)] = b
```

That you can convert to one-liner to get `i` with list comprehension.

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks. But I have several questions - does moving an axis do a huge work of shuffling whole data of `a`? Does moveaxis change underlying `a` or it returns a copy? Also - as I understand after moving axis and assigning I need to move axis back? Or moving axis doesn't do any work just creates a lightweight writable view?

Comment: @Arty `np.moveaxis` creates a view. You can check for yourself with `np.shares_memory(np.moveaxis(a,axis,0), a)` and so on. Also, if it were a copy, you wouldn't be able to assign.

Comment: @Arty So there is no single function like `np.put()` but supporting multi-dimensionality?

Comment: BTW, what is the heavy version of `moveaxis()` that actually really changes layout of array in memory?

Comment: @Arty There's no heavy version. Added `np.put_along_axis` based one if you are a fan of builtins.

Comment: @Arty If you meant a new memory space by that changing layout, you might be looking to make a copy? Not sure what you are getting at though.

Comment: What about `np.transpose()` does it also just permutes view of axes but doesn't shuffle cells of array in memory? Same as `moveaxis`?

Comment: I'll explain why I was also interested in heavy version - because sometimes when I swap axes I really want to have reshuffled layout, because next code will be much more cache friendly if last axes layout will be used, i.e. accessing sub-arrays will be sequential instead of jumping through far away memory regions. So are you saying that if I do `np.copy()` after `moveaxis` than array gets really reshuffled in memory?

Comment: Probably I found a mistake in your answer - `i = [slice(None)]*b.ndim` should probably have `a.ndim` instead.